# Is there a way to use an element although its not on screen anymore?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

After I've found an element ,lets say a `span`. 
Is there a way to save its attributes ,or something of that sort, so that ill be able to "click" the `span` even if it does not exist on screen anymore ?

What i need, is a way to access the page its pointing to after doing some actions which removes the `span` from the screen.

*I understand that watir-webdriver is for GUI testing and therefore is supposed to allow only actions a human-being can perform. But i was hoping there is still a way.*

Answer (score 4):

I would need to see the source of your web page, but generally you could do it like this:

```
1.9.3p392 :001 > require "watir-webdriver"
 => true 
1.9.3p392 :002 > b = Watir::Browser.start "stackoverflow.com"
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x7f93652a09b4f1a2 url="http://stackoverflow.com/" title="Stack Overflow">
```

#### Define a new variable

```
1.9.3p392 :004 > a = b.span(:id, "hlinks-custom").a(:text, "about").href
 => "http://stackoverflow.com/about"
```

#### Click on another link

```
   1.9.3p392 :005 > b.a(:text, 'faq').click
     => [] 
    1.9.3p392 :006 > b.title
     => "Frequently Asked Questions - Stack Overflow"
```

#### Finally re-direct your browser to pre-set variable 'a'

```
1.9.3p392 :007 > b.goto a
 => "http://stackoverflow.com/about"
```

Comment: As far as i can tell , a hold a url ,not an element . 
And thats why when you type `b.goto a` it works.

Comment: You cannot click on something that does not exist in the DOM, that's never going to work. Just as a real user could not go to page n+1 and then click on something on page n (unless they tell the browser to go back)  You are always going to get some form of could not be located, or other error indicating the item does not exist, or no longer exists.    The best you can do is as shown above, get the destination you would go to if you clicked the link, button, etc, and then send the browser to that url.

Comment: @ Chuck van der Linden - I can do so if the `href` is a url , what if its `javascript:void(0)` ?

@Sveatoslav Circel - I cant really show the code . its just a `span` that directs to a different page. Chuck understood what i needed (clicking on something fon page n from page n+1) 

I guess its not possible after all (Unless there is a url inthe href tag.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way, just save the element when it exists and use it later. Here is an example where watir drives to google.com and as you see "mark..." printed you may close the browser and will see that the variable "element" still holds the value of what was in it...

```
  require 'watir';

  ie = Watir::Browser.new();
  ie.goto("google.com");
  puts("mark...");
  element = ie.span(:id, "gbqfsa").html();
  sleep(5);
  #close the browser while you sleep...
  puts(element);
```

It prints the html value of the element, therefore it still keeps the refence

Comment: It does not work . it keeps the element details , but when i try to click it i get the fallowing error : `Element must be displayed to click (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)`

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to click on something that no longer exists?  that is exactly the sort of error I would expect to see in that situation.

Comment: Im not surprised. 
That was exactly my question : although i know watir designed to perform actions human does , is there still a possibility to save an element for later use. and from your answer i gather there isnt.